# How can I update the contents of a ComboBox embedded in a GridX

Tags: combobox, dojo, gridx

I am in the process of altering an existing GridX table to add a new column which contains a drop down, the contents of which will be different for each row.

I have added the dropdown as a combobox by setting the cell's structure as

```
widgetsInCell: true,
```

Which will make the combobox's cell a decorator.

My issue now is that the update function operates by getting the gridx's and setting a new store.That works for text data but I can't find a way of creating a store which will populate the combobox.

Do I need to integrate somehow with the cell's **setCellValue** hook?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`
[dojo FilteringSelect](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html)

If all your rows data from same store, use query to filtering data.(e.g. query: {state: /.*/})

Otherwise use `"dojo/store/JsonRest"` get data from server.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I also found that I need to set the passed in store in the combobox's setCellValue.